# How can I implement the Observer pattern in a Firefox Extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, observer-pattern

I'm trying to implement a simple Observer pattern within a Firefox extension. This initially appears relatively easy, but I thought it made sense to get the functionality from a library

- [JS.Observable](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/observable.html) seemed like a good option, but I found that JS.Class is unhappy running from within an extension as the DOM is not where it expects it to be, etc.
- JQuery's [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) appears to offer an alternative and apparently JQuery should work inside the extension's context. This relies on binding to a DOM object which seems a little nasty for what I'm trying to do.
- YUI's [Custom Event](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#customevent) seems ideal, but YUI does not work inside extensions.

Is there a good implementation of the Observer pattern that I can use, or should I just write it by hand following something like [this from O'Reilly Answers](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2190-two-examples-of-the-observer-pattern-in-javascript/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working completely in chrome code, I would just use the [Observer Service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsiobserverservice).

Answer (score 0):

The [Publish/Subscribe with jQuery Custom Events](http://weblog.bocoup.com/publishsubscribe-with-jquery-custom-events) blog post explained that JQuery's bind could be applied to any object, not just a DOM object. So, that's the solution I've gone with, I followed [A Guide To Using jQuery Inside Firefox Extension](http://meherranjan.com/blog/a-guide-to-using-jquery-inside-firefox-extension/) to get JQuery working nicely inside my namespaced extension.

Comment: using jquery for a firefox extension is a very very bad idea, it's slow, bloated, and error prone.